# Axios.get returning 404

Tags: react-native, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am so frustrated that I am resorting to the community to help me out on this issue.

This is something I guess is very trivial but is not working for me.
This DID work until recently. I apparently changed something or something has changed.

I am creating a react native app and the user is able to give his address and I am using googles geocoding API to make sure the address the user is giving actually exists.

This is what I am doing:

```
const { country, city, street, streetNumber } = user;
const address = `${street} ${streetNumber}, ${city}, ${country}`;

const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`;

const request = axios.get(URL);

request.then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
});
```

As I said before this used to work but now I am getting this error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

However, if i copy and paste the URL to my browser with the address and the API Key I do get a response from the server!!

What is going on???

I recently installed `react-native-fetch-blob` and since then it apparently broke but it is not certain. Please, any help is appreciated.

EDIT:!!

If I hardcode the URL to this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Carrer%20de%20ali%20bei+113,+Barcelona,+Espa%C3%B1a&key=APIKEY`

it actually works. This has to be an API issue right?

Comment: just a question, are you trying to do string concatination with that `+` signs? ``${street}+${streetNumber},+${city},+${country}``

Comment: @Sag1v I removed them. Those are not supposed to be there. It is still giving me an error.

Comment: another question just to be sure, i suppose that `GOOGLE_API_KEY` is not a variable you forgot to pass right? it's just for this example...

Comment: @Sag1v No, the API Key is getting imported from another file. It does exist.

Comment: Quick suggestion: `catch` errors from your `promise` explicitly. And instead of assigning response from `axios` to a variable, just `then` it straightaway. Don't know if that will help you. But you can try and see.

Comment: @Mekicha thanks for the advice. In my code I always catch promises, just for the sake of the example I omitted it.

Comment: Before making the request, do a `console.log(URL)`. What does it come back with? A few things may be wrong here, e.g. malformed URL, not encoding the params, leaving out `+` signs which are present in your hard coded URL but not your `address` variable.

Comment: @Dan I did just that and the URL is fine. The thing that makes me crazy is that the request worked before but suddenly stopped working.